# UIManager and JCheckBox icon

Tags: java, swing, uimanager

My GUI has JTable with column that has boolean type which is being showed as a JCheckBox. Metal colors don't suit to my GUI, so I used next code:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MyGUI.class.getResource("resources/checkbox1.png"));
UIManager.put("CheckBox.icon", icon1);
```

I got unselected checkbox I wanted, but there's no key in UIManager that I can change to customize selected JCheckBox.
Is there way to change selected JCheckBox view globally? 
P.S. I tried both and opaque and transparent background, result is the same - checkbox doesn't work as it has to.

Comment: [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Override the `paintIcon` method of `Icon` to draw different icons when it's selected or not.

[This is a stack overflow answer demos how to implement a tri-states `JCheckBox`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26749548/6041964)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution on the internet and changed it for myself.

```
class CheckBoxIcon implements Icon {
    public void paintIcon(Component component, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        AbstractButton abstractButton = (AbstractButton)component;
        ButtonModel buttonModel = abstractButton.getModel();

        if(buttonModel.isSelected()) 
            g.drawImage(createImage("resources/checkbox2.png"), x, y, component);
        else
            g.drawImage(createImage("resources/checkbox1.png"), x, y, component);
    }
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return 13;
    }
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return 13;
    }

    protected Image createImage(String path) {
        URL imageURL = CheckBoxIcon.class.getResource(path);
        Image icn = null;

        if (imageURL == null) {
            if(null==icn){
                //System.out.println("path: "+path);
                icn = new ImageIcon (MyGUI.class.getResource(path)).getImage();
                if(null!=icn)
                    return icn;
                else{ 
                    System.err.println("Resource not found: " + path);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return null;
        } else {
            return (new ImageIcon(imageURL)).getImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use this line in code.

```
UIManager.put("CheckBox.icon", new CheckBoxIcon());
```