# set a jCheckBox to indeterminate

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I have a program that uses jCheckBoxes. basically, each checkbox controls a number of other checkboxes. I need the parent checkbox to be in the indeterminate state if the other checkboxes do not all contain the same value. But if the user clicks the indeterminate checkbox, they should be able to cycle between checked and unchecked only (i.e. they cannot switch back to indeterminate), which would in turn change the values of all the other boxes to match. Similarly, if the user changes the value of one of the sub check boxes, the parent checkbox should switch back to indeterminate. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you post some code you'll get an answer faster

Comment: It sounds to me like you are describing a check box tree with the parent/child relationship. JIDE Common Layer (http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) provides this. If you don't want a tree then you are describing a tristate checkbox. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263323/tristate-checkboxes-in-java for various solutions.

Comment: Tri state isn't a valid state of `JCheckBox`...go figure, you could have a look at [this](http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue082.html) implementation...